# to say contemplatively

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a verb that expresses in one word to say/utter something in a contemplative manner, maybe with a hint of melancholy, with one's mind wandering off and thinking of the whole irony of being....

E.g. Sic transit gloria mundi, he ____ (said contemplatively).

Comment: How does “he ***mused***” strike you?

Comment: like a nail on the head

Answer (score 1):

I would use the word "pensively".   By the way, I think that in this situation, his mind was "wandering", not "wondering".   --  Autodidact

Comment: The problem with *pensively* is that it is not a verb like OP asks for.

Answer (score 1):

Sic transit gloria mundi, he ***mused***

[Oxford Learners Dictionary says](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/us/definition/english/muse_2)

> ***muse:*** to say something to yourself in a way that shows you are thinking carefully about it